# Node js Console

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

I want to take user input in Node JS Console. As we take input from user in C++ console like
cin>>takeInput;

I didn't try any method because I don't know much about Node JS. I am just beginner in learning Node JS. I tried the prompt-sync method of NodeJS by googling but I didn't succeed. I read NodeJS documentation and did as documentation says but still I am not getting the results which I was expecting.

Comment: try searching for "nodejs input from console"

Comment: "*I didn't try any method*"  You could have at least tried searching google or this site ...

Comment: "*I am not getting the results which I was expecting.*" As a start, show us a [mre] of the code that doesn't conform to your requirements.

Answer (score -2):

Try to use ***readline*** module in node.js, it provides an interface for reading the data from readable stream.

To create a readline interface, use the `createInterface` method, specifying (`process.stdin`) as the input stream (where user input will be read from) and (`process.stdout`) as the output stream (where the output will be written).

Note: ***process*** is a global object in Node.js. It provides information about, and control over, the current Node.js process. It's part of the Node.js runtime environment and is available globally in all modules.

Here is an example:

```js
const readline = require('readline');
const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});
        
rl.question('Enter something: ', (userInput) => {
  console.log(`You entered: ${userInput}`);
  rl.close();
});
```

Comment: Please don't post answers to such ovious duplicates but vote to close them with the respective reason (I'm aware, you don't have enough reputation to do so. But posting answers to duplicates won't change that)

Comment: @derpirscher i apologize for the misunderstanding, i didn't notice the linked question in your previous replay